# SharePoint GUID: uppercase or lowercase?

Tags: sharepoint, guid

Does it matter that I use lowercase or uppercase letters in GUID for Sharepoint development?  I'm not sure if there are certain situations where lowercase letters need to be used instead of uppercase ones.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It shouldn't matter what casing you are using, though most people tend to use uppercase in SharePoint-development.

It could matter though, if curly brackets are used or not. I'm not sure if this bug has been fixed in the service packs but here's a small article on the brackets:

http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/archive/2007/10/26/To-bracket-or-not-to-bracket-GUIDs-in-SharePoint-CAML.aspx

Answer (score 2):

No it does not matter. All GUIDs are created equally (harhar)

Comment: I hope that they interally are made with new Guid() method.